# Datatables creating dropdown list for every row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using datatable's to list data on my .net mvc application.
Currently i'm trying to create a selectlist on every row with data pulled from db for selectlist. My code follows

```
    {
                  data: "State",
                  render: function (data, type, row) {
                      var resultHtml = '';

                      if (type == "display") {

                          $.post("/SystemDefinitions/JsonGetDeviceStatusByCompany", {}, function (data, status) {
                              resultHtml += '<select id="jsonStatusList">';
                              $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                  if (item.DeviceStatusID == row.State) {
                                      resultHtml += '<option id="' + item.DeviceStatusID + '" selected="selected">' + item.StatusName + '<option>';
                                  }
                                  else {
                                      resultHtml += '<option id="' + item.DeviceStatusID + '">' + item.StatusName + '<option>';

                                  }
                                  resultHtml += '</select>;';
                              });

                          });
                          return resultHtml;
                      }

                      return data;
                  }

              }
```

with console.log method i'am able to see the created html code but the code does not displaying anything on page. Is something wrong with the code or it's not possible to populate selectlist on that stage.

Thank you.

Comment: This is missing relevant tags (HTML, Javascript/jQuery?)

Comment: the line `return data;` is always being hit, you need an `else` in there somewhere otherwise `resultHtml` will never get returned

Comment: even if i remove the return data; line, nothings change.  somehow resultHtml variable returns empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's happening because your code returns `resultHtml` before Ajax POST request is completed.

You need to do `$.post` before initializing the table, in one way or the other.

For example, you can initialize your table in a callback for `$.post`.

```js
$.post("/SystemDefinitions/JsonGetDeviceStatusByCompany", {}, function (dataDeviceStatus, status) {
   $('#example').DataTable({
      // ... skipped ...
      columns: [ 
         // ... skipped ...
         {
            data: "State",
            render: function (data, type, row) {
               if (type == "display") {
                  data = '<select id="jsonStatusList">';

                  $.each(dataDeviceStatus, function (i, item) {
                     if (item.DeviceStatusID == row.State) {
                         data += '<option id="' + item.DeviceStatusID + '" selected="selected">' + item.StatusName + '<option>';
                     } else {
                         data += '<option id="' + item.DeviceStatusID + '">' + item.StatusName + '<option>';

                     }
                  });

                  data += '</select>;';
               }

               return data;
            }       
         }
      }
   ]
});
```

Alternatively you can initialize your table before `$.post` but you need to call `draw(false)` API method to redraw the table once Ajax request has been completed.